# Is it possible to limit the output on a maven build?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, maven-2, tdd

The team I am on has maven-ized our project AND taken on TDD as a way of life, but due to the sheer size of the project and the number of our tests, our build is taking roughly 15-20 minutes. It's AWESOME that we have as much test coverage as we do, but it isn't exactly the quick turn around that we would like.

There are pages, and pages, and pages, and pages of output that is sent to the console when we are doing a full build, and I know that writing to the console can be costly. Is there any way to **tune** maven in a way that some of that output can be reduced? Is this even an issue or should I be looking for other ways to shave some time off our build?

Comment: Offload the build to a CI server, such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) which will send you emails on build breaks and test failures. Also, any decent IDE is able to limit the unit testing to specific packages, subprojects etc.

Comment: The question is also if your tests are really unit tests and not mixed with integration test which can be costly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assume that writing to the console is the bottleneck. Is the writing done by maven ( e.g. many plugin invocations, recording tests being executed ) or by our own code?

If your code is outputting to much, then you should deploy a logging configuration file ( Log4j, Logback etc ) in the `src/test/resources` directory and suppress all logging output.

If you're bothered by what Maven itself writes, run it with the `-q` flag:

> -q,--quiet                             Quiet output - only show errors

This will at least allow you to validate that writing to console is the problem ( which I'm not that certain about ).

Comment: logback is expected to have performance improvment compared to log4j. You can have a look on `AsyncAppender` too

Comment: At this point, I'm just looking for cheap gains... there is so much output that looking at what goes to the console is on the table. I'll give your -q suggestion a shot, thanks!

Comment: Tried it, and there is alot less output, but still quite a bit gets sent to the console. I'll post later if that equates into shaving any time off of the build.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also considered to check if you can parallelize your Maven Builds?
By default, Maven does not utilize the full power of your hardware. It builds all modules sequentially rather than in parallel. **You can check by Maven commands to analyze your project including the dependency graph and build the project in parallel where possible.** You can either specify the exact number of threads to use for building your project or use a portable version of the parameter and specify the number of thread in terms of CPUs available on the machine.

**mvn -T 4 install** -- will use 4 threads

**mvn -T 1C install** -- will use 1 thread per available CPU core.

While it might happen that your project is not easy to build in parallel it’s worth trying, the speedup can be substantial. Using one thread per CPU core is a good default.